# How to fix return request.get_json and get null in web?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I am trying to use flask-socket to request json from a client and want to return this object to the web. I try to print the object it is work in terminal but show null when I open local host. How can I fix this?

Or should I user socket in client to send message and get it in server?

Code for `Server`:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message():
    jsonData = request.get_json()
    print(jsonData)
    return jsonify(jsonData)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Code for `Client`:

```py
import requests
while 1:
    requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', json={"mytext": "lalala"})
```

I want the on the web can display `the json data from my client side such as{"mytext":"lalala"}` instead of null. [My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNhPJ.png).. 
In addition, I want to pass a dynamic value from my client side and return it on the web.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: When the request method is GET you are not returning anything

Comment: Your code works, if both scripts (server and client) are actually run as python scripts. But when you open it inside a browser (like i assume you did in the picture), you do not call POST, you call GET. So maybe a better explanation what your expected behaviour has to be would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . So should I type if methods='post' and then return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In order to retrieve key-value pairs

  - For a `GET request`: you have to use `request.args` [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args)
  - For a `POST request`: you have to use `request.get_json()` [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json)

For a request to get a path parameter, you have to register your param as such [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations)

```
@app.route('/<name>', methods=['GET'])
def add_message_get_param(name):
    print(name)
    return jsonify({'name': name})
```

Now as you've stated, you want to pass a json. But your browser screenshot indicates that you call your endpoint with `/hello`. In order to pass a key-value pair, you'll have to do something like `/?mykey=myvalue`. I've added the path parameter for completeness

Thus, your server has to become

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def add_message_get():
    jsonData = request.args
    print(jsonData)
    return jsonify(jsonData)

@app.route('/<name>', methods=['GET'])
def add_message_get_param(name):
    print(name)
    return jsonify({'name': name})

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def add_message_post():
    jsonData = request.get_json()
    print(jsonData)
    return jsonify(jsonData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1')
```

and your client for debugging purposes:

```
import requests

result = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', json={"mytext":"lalala"})
print(f'POST result: {result.text}')

result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/?mytext=lalala')
print(f'GET result: {result.text}')

result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/Antonis')
print(f'GET result: {result.text}')
```

Comment: What I want is sending a value from client to server, and it can be return and display on the web to be requested by other clients.  I have a question on here is that the json={"mytext":"lalala"} is sending from the client-side?

Comment: @JieGuan if you update your server.py according to the posted snippet above, you can try and click http://127.0.0.1:5000/?mytext=lalala

Comment: Thanks for your information.  But how the value in my client effect this? If the data in client side is a dynamic value, how can I make update to server? Thanks

Comment: @JieGuan 3 main "problems"
a) a GET request handling differentiates from a POST request handling
b) you need to pass a query string parameter and not a path parameter
* `/hello` treats `hello` as path parameter
* `/?message=hello` treats `message=hello` as query string parameter and doing `request.get_json()` will return you a `{'message': 'hello'}`
c) your initial method couldn't successfully handle the GET request from your browser, while your `client.py` was doing a POST request

Comment: Thanks again, but I still confuse about how can I return the json from the client side?  if I have data=data+1, and json = {'data' = data}, how can I request this and return in my server side?

Comment: @JieGuan hopefully a screenshot will be more helpful :) https://i.imgur.com/FZvyzMz.png GET request implementation in server + GET request from firefox + GET request from python client

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.data` from

```
return jsonify(jsonData).data
```

Comment: It return the null too. I delete some of the line of my code to make it simple.